# SQL 2008, week numbers and years

Tags: sql-server-2008

Having some problems getting the information I need from the database. I fell foul of the week vs iso_week setting in DATEPART but have now got the problem of getting the year from it. The nub of the issue is that when I run

```
SELECT datePart(iso_week, '2014-12-29');

SELECT datePart(week, '2014-12-29');

SELECT datePart(YEAR, '2014-12-29');
```

I get Wk 1 for the first query, Wk 53 for the second. (first being what I want) but the year is still 2014. So if I do

```
SELECT CONCAT('WK', RIGHT(CONCAT('00', DATEPART(iso_week, '2014-12-29')), 2), ' ',  DATEPART(year, '2014-12-29'))
```

I get WK01 2014 instead of WK01 2015.

Anyone know a way I can get the right ISO week and the associated year for a date?

Edit:

See if I can clear up a bit here.

Not expecting the above to return 2015 instead of 2014, that would be daft. What I need is a way to know that the week number returned is actually in the next year. I did consider doing a straight if week > 52 then its wk 1 in the next year, but that seems a little sledgehammerish and I am not sure it will actually work.

Comment: Are you kidding? `DATEPART(year, '2014-12-29')`??? `I get WK01 2014 instead of WK01 2015.` Why on earth Sql Server would return 2015?

Comment: Not saying it should return 2015, it is right to return 2014. Totally agree. What I need though is a way to link the iso_week output to the year that isn't datepart(year, '') I was hoping that there was a datepart(iso_year) type thing that could give me back the year a week would exist in even though the year is actually 2014.

Comment: I think you have your own answer: if `DATEPART(WEEK) = 53`, then it is clearly `DATEPART(YEAR....) + 1`

Comment: Had someone point out that there could be a week 53 in a year. This year for example has one [link]http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php[/link] Which confirms what I thought that it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had someone set me on the right track with some simple logic. I was trying to over complicate things. This seems to work for everything I can throw at it.

```
DECLARE @date AS DATETIME
SET @date = '2014-12-29'

SELECT
    CAST(
    CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(@Date) = 1 AND DATEPART(iso_week, @date) > 51 THEN YEAR(@Date) - 1
        WHEN MONTH(@Date) = 12 AND DATEPART(iso_week, @date) = 1 THEN YEAR(@Date) + 1
        ELSE YEAR(@Date)
    END
    AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Year
,
RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(iso_week, @date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS Week
```

It seems to cover true wk53 occurrences and incorrect ones.

Answer (score 2):

You should understand how the `ISO_WEEK` is calculated. From [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

> ISO 8601 includes the ISO week-date system, a numbering system for
>   weeks. **Each week is associated with the year in which Thursday occurs**.
>   For example, week 1 of 2004 (2004W01) ran from Monday 29 December 2003
>   to Sunday, 4 January 2004. The highest week number in a year might be
>   52 or 53. This style of numbering is typically used in European
>   countries/regions, but rare elsewhere.

Hence your `DATEPART(YEAR, ...)` you should pass in the Thursday on or after December 29, 2014.

Comment: That is good to know, most of the documentation I found assumes you know when the iso week starts. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT('WK', RIGHT(CONCAT('00', DATEPART(iso_week, '2014-12-29') % 53), 2), ' ',  DATEPART(year, '2014-12-29') + DATEPART(iso_week, '2014-12-29') % 53)
```

Comment: Almost, although on a true wk53 it returns wk00.